# Get user-id selection screen in login as with desktop applications instead of entering user-id every time

Tags: ios, adal

Using iOS ADAL SDK, how to get user-id "selection" screen in login as with desktop applications instead of entering user-id every time?

The only thing I am able to analyze which should be related to this is `ADPromptBehavior`. But the comments in the SDK has no option to what I am looking for.

```
typedef enum
{
    /*!
        Default option. Users will be prompted only if their attention is needed. First the cache will
        be checked for a suitable access token (non-expired). If none is found, the cache will be checked
        for a suitable refresh token to be used for obtaining a new access token. If this attempt fails
        too, it depends on the acquireToken method being called.
        acquireTokenWithResource methods will prompt the user to re-authorize the resource usage by providing
        credentials. If user login cookies are present from previous authorization, the webview will be
        displayed and automatically dismiss itself without asking the user to re-enter credentials.
        acquireTokenSilentWithResource methods will not show UI in this case, but fail with error code
        AD_ERROR_USER_INPUT_NEEDED.
     */
    AD_PROMPT_AUTO,

    /*!
        The user will be prompted explicitly for credentials, consent or any other prompts, except when the
        user has Azure Authenticator installed. This option is useful in multi-user scenarios. Example is
        authenticating for the same e-mail service with different user.
     */
    AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS,

    /*!
        Re-authorizes (through displaying webview) the resource usage, making sure that the resulting access
        token contains updated claims. If user logon cookies are available, the user will not be asked for
        credentials again and the logon dialog will dismiss automatically. This is equivalent to passing
        prompt=refresh_session as an extra query parameter during the authorization.
     */
    AD_PROMPT_REFRESH_SESSION,

    /*!
        If Azure Authenticator is installed forces it to prompt the user, otherwise has the same behavior as
        AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS.
     */
    AD_FORCE_PROMPT,
} ADPromptBehavior;
```

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do this is to install the Microsoft Authenticator app and use "brokered authentication" with ADAL. This will send the user out of your app and into the Authenticator where they can se SSO if already authenticated or select from the list or configured accounts.  It can't work with non-brokered login because the in-app browser session has no cookies to provide details of their previous logins. It is like logging in from a new computer each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an open issue in GitHub repository for ADAL related to this. It seems there is a prompt value called `select_account` in the .NET version of the `ADAL` which is not present in the iOS version as of now.

However, this can be acheived by passing `prompt=select_account` in the `extraQueryParameters` parameter.

Reference: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/1379